# Is this principle indubitable?

Tags: epistemology

Principle: One should be certain in a proposition p if and only if one should be at least as confident in p as in every other proposition.

Is this principle indubitable?

Comment: So you define "certainty" as the maximum of the "level of confidence". How to define and measure "level of confidence" ?

Comment: See also [Certainty](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/certainty/#KinCer).

Comment: Are you as confident of this proposition as you are of every other proposition?  I do so wonder why there are not more people who believe in solipsism.

Comment: It seems rather obviously false, at least on the usual meaning of "certainty". What if someone is in a scattered state, and not too sure of anything?

Comment: Certainty is certainty, not a variable quantity dependent on relative values.

Comment: @Conifold there's a 'should' there, which I assume is intended to make it apply only to ideally rational inferences. But that's a good point, I've corrected my answer to make the assumption explicit.

Comment: @Schiphol I do not see how inferences (and hence "ideal rationality") are at all relevant. What one believes is ultimately based on judgments, and how confident one is in their judgments has little to do with inferring. And even ideal reasoners should not be certain of anything simply because they are more confident about it than about other things. There has to be some baseline standard to clear.

Comment: I del reasoners should presumably be certain of (p or not p) for many p, and of many lógico-mathematical truths, but let's leave it there.

Answer (score 2):

Your principle looks plausible enough (assuming that the 'should' there is the 'should' of ideal rationality) but, I would say, it is too complex to elicit clear "indubitability" intuitions. You could propose it as a definition of certainty, or derive it as a theorem in some calculus (if you are developing an epistemic logic, say.)

Anyway, whether a bunch of internet people find your principle indubitable is not terribly interesting. It's perhaps more productive to think of statements such as the one in your question in terms of their theoretical fruitfulness. What do we gain if we accept that this principle is true? Are we then able to explain more things, solve a little paradox, formalize an intuitively appealing philosophical argument?

Answer (score 0):

I think it better acknowledges the complexity of the concept of 'certainty' to consider it more along the lines of the experience an individual has while considering a proposition rather than something intrinsic to the proposition or how the proposition is related to other propositions (with the latter being how I am understanding the aim of your principle).

I find myself compelled to quote Wittgenstein's statement 30 from 'On Certainty' [emphasis my own]:

"When someone has made sure of something, they say: "Yes, the calculation is correct," but this is not inferred from the condition of certainty." One does not infer how things are from one's one certainty. **Certainty is as it were a tone of voice in which one declares how things are**, but one does not infer from the tone of voice that one is justified."